# FlatList ref issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am not getting `ref` of the `flatlist` always getting

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
>   this ref will fail. Did you mean to use `React.forwardRef()`?

I am beginner in react-native

```
export default class ListData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flatListRef: null
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={countryList}
          ref={ref => (this.state.flatListRef = ref)}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={[styles.ListViewContainer]}>
              <Text style={styles.countryTxt}>
                <Text> +{item.code}</Text>
                <Text> {item.CountryName} </Text>
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't do `this.state.flatListRef`, just `this.flatListRef`

Comment: @Vivek_Neel No luck, still getting same error. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using `import { FlatList } from "react-native"`
instead of
`import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

is working. But I am still want to why it's not working with 'react-native-gesture-handler'. while list is displaying correctly but ref is not getting.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your constructor

`this.flatListRef = React.createRef()`

and then in your FlatList you do:

`<FlatList ref={this.flatListRef} ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `ref={null}` to your list item component.

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
  <View style={[styles.ListViewContainer]} ref={null}>
```

Comment: Passing ref={null} to the <FlatList itself worked for me